# Shell: Map all keys in a string format (json compatible)

Tags: json, shell, object, jq

I have an object in a file like:

### foo.txt

```
{
"methods" :
      {
        0 : "GET",
      },
}
```

I would like to convert to json with `jq` or some other shell converter. Specifically I want to turn each key into a string `0` -> `"0"`. Keys can be numerical or alphanumerical.

### Update

Any other tool is also acceptable. Anything that gets the job done. Preferably a shell tool.

Comment: jq can process JSON (but your input isn't) or raw text (but you'd need to write a JSON parser, tweaked to accept objects with integer keys (and commas present after the last field), which would be tedious), so you'd probably be better off using another tool.

Comment: Any tool is fine... something that can be automated easily. I would rather not spin a php server to do this.

Answer (score 1):

With [hjson](https://github.com/laktak/hjson-py) (using Python), you could use the `-j` flag

```
  -j            Output as formatted JSON.
```

as follows:

```bash
hjson -j yourfile.txt
```

```json
{
  "methods": {
    "0": "GET"
  }
}
```

---

Another way could be using the YAML processor [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (written in Go) and its `-o` flag

```
  -o, --output-format string          [yaml|y|json|j|props|p|xml|x] output format type. (default "yaml")
```

as follows

```bash
yq -o json yourfile.txt
```

```json
{
  "methods": {
    "0": "GET"
  }
}
```

But yq also has a JSON converter `@json` as built-in function, if you'd want to further adjust the data on the fly:

```bash
yq '@json' yourfile.txt
```

```json
{"methods":{"0":"GET"}}
```